# When changing the paint color, existing strokes get changed, too

Tags: android, colors, paint

I am capturing the drawing using the code below. For changing the stroke color or width, I am calling the `setPaintAttribute()` method. But when I change the color, the whole drawing gets changed including the lines that I drew before. How can I change the color of the paint and leave previous drawings untouched? I tried to create a new Path, but then the previous drawing disappears.

```
public void setPaintAttributes(float STROKE_WIDTH, int color)
    {
        paint=new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(color);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
    }
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        scrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        btnSaveSignature.setEnabled(true);
        btnSaveSignature.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.save);
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();           

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
            lastTouchX = eventX;
            lastTouchY = eventY;
            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);
            int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
            for (int i = 0; i < historySize; i++) {
                float historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i);
                float historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i);
                path.lineTo(historicalX, historicalY);
            }
            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
            break;
        }

        invalidate((int) (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH));

        lastTouchX = eventX;
        lastTouchY = eventY;

        return true;
    }

    private void resetDirtyRect(float eventX, float eventY) {
        dirtyRect.left = Math.min(lastTouchX, eventX);
        dirtyRect.right = Math.max(lastTouchX, eventX);
        dirtyRect.top = Math.min(lastTouchY, eventY);
        dirtyRect.bottom = Math.max(lastTouchY, eventY);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, anyone got solution.? I'm struggling to fix this issue. Please help me.

Comment: While touching the screen, touch only recognized, there is not a dot is drawn. Is this a issue in android signature capture?

Answer (score 2):

create an arraylist which contains pair of path and paint,then add each path to arraylist,it works for me,

```
ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>> paths = new ArrayList<Pair<Path, Paint>>();
```

Use as below:

```
    mCanvas = new Canvas();
    mPath = new Path();
    Paint newPaint = new Paint(mPaint);
    paths.add(new Pair<Path, Paint>(mPath, newPaint));
```